# Unable to test sandbox accounts on paypal

Tags: paypal

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="6DHWKYCKBGXFS">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I have been trying it for weeks but no luck. what i have done so far is created two accounts on developer site then with business account i created donate button whose code is above.I pasted it on plain html page and it directed me to
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=bnXFinACSxCb1ODnXhGUvOIt9PAh_P89ZBULZpUJW...
where i entered my buyer account but i dont know why its keep sayiing "Please check your emai and password" .  i have checked it hundred of times but i dont know why its not accepting this.Please help me , I am in big trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Finaly after trying for weeks I found the solutuion.The four point in this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_test-pps-buttons/ tutorial is wrong. You dont create a button like that for testing purpose but rather go to profile>selling tools>create new button . Probably it will be helpful for someone..

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to tested this with your test buyer accounts, your seller accounts also needs to be set up in the sandbox.  The above code is pointing to the live site "www.paypal.com", if you are trying to use your test seller and buyer accounts, the URL needs to be "www.sandbox.paypal.com"

Comment: yeah you are right. i created seller account on developers site "prince_ov_yemen-facilitator@hotmail.com" and explicitly changed the url  that u mentioned because everytime i log in to my seller account and try to create my button it gives me the code pointing to orignal site .but now it gives me following error "PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem"

Comment: i am following this tutorial https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_test-pps-buttons/

Comment: do i have to replace the value of hosted_button_id with something else?